# How to filter request to Firebase realtime database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have this chat structure:
[image: Data structure]

I now want to filer chats, so the user sees only chats where he is the member of the chat.
As you can see every chat has members node, there is userId from firebase.
How I can filter that in my request?
Now I retrieve chats like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { chats: [] };
    this.getChats = this.getChats.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var _userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    this.getChats(_userId);
  }

  getChats = _userId => {
    var readedData = firebase
      .database()
      .ref('chats')
      .orderByKey();
    readedData.once('value', snapshot => {
      this.setState({ chats: snapshot.val() });
      console.log(this.state.chats);
    });
  };
```

Thanks for the help!
New structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
//....
var uid = 'NGIKTy2......';   //Set the member userId
var readedData = firebase
  .database()
  .ref('chats')
  .orderByChild('members/' + uid)
  .equalTo(true)
//....
```

Corresponding documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: Can you check my eddited question, image 2 how i should check now if my node is changed like this?

Comment: You would need to loop over the first level children.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to my node, because I don't quite understand how. I just need to check if there is userId.